# Restrict url access just from a specific site

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, iframe, restriction

I have an application hosted on distant server and it will be loaded by other site in an iframe, it there a way to restrict the access to it,  I mean prevent the access to it  by using its url, and give the access to that site only

Comment: It's not possible with PHP, but possibly with javascript. Do you have any control over the "other site" that has the iframe?

Comment: yes I would have controle, but how com it is not possible on php? how about http?

Comment: Because PHP is server side and has no way of knowing if the browser is going to load a page in a frame or not. When the HTTP request is made for a page, it doesn't send anything that indicates it's loading in a frame (that I know of).

Comment: there no secret key to load a url for example?